# Jmeter does not redirect properly, the way browser does

Tags: url, redirect, jmeter

Jmeter does not redirect properly, the way browser does

I have URL1, which when invoked redirects to URL2.

The part of re-directed URL2 like parameter id number is dynamically generated as shown below

Following is status code and redirection captured from a normal invocation through browser

Jmeter http sampler /request has two options "Redirect automatically" and "Follow redirect"

Problem:
Selecting "Redirect automatically" does nt seem to working , as the page corresponding to URL is not loaded

However, for some reason on invoking URL1 through jmeter, it returns status code as 200 OK, which means jmeter was not able to capture intermediate status code of 302 hence was not able to capture redirected URL

Now the question I have

1) How to make jmeter does redirection correctly
2) How to capture redirected url from response header field of URL1, assuming the response code of URL1 shows as OK, ie 302 for redirection status

Please help

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does work as browser do, just check "Follow Redirects".

It is more flexible than browsers as it allows you to have control on intermediate pages to extract some data or assert things.

If redirect doesn't work then either it's a missing token in your simulation or a bug although there is no identified bug on this in JMeter 3.3

So ensure you use it and if issue persists, ask on their user mailing list and if confirmed open a bug.

Comment: Hi UBIK LOAD PACK,

yes, the parameters data I have compared with Fiddler and both sending the same expect few UNIQUE Ids. 

when we capture from Fiddler it shows 302 redirect but when run same from JMeter (verified both Auto redirect, Follow Redirect) it is giving 200 code instead of 302.

I don't know where is the problem, there are no issues by passing parameters, all are matching when I verify with Fiddler. But why the JMeter is getting 200 instead of 302.

Comment: I have to capture unique id from the Response Header if it get 302. So if the request get 302 then only I can get the Unique ID and use in the Next Step. but JMeter is getting 200.

you can check the request parameters from below URL .. JMeter passed Vs. Browser passed.


  [1]: https://www.diffchecker.com/RF2YhZRq

Comment: Most probably the differing parameters are the issue and are the result of some computation (checksum) or some previous extraction, did you do this correlation work ? If not  that's what explains the 200 instead of 302. Your submission is failing

Comment: the different parameters already captured from previous extraction and passed. those are correct.